# Calculate the swiss tennis ranking classification

Tags: r, function, formula

The Swiss tennis ranking is calculated using the classification value `C`

`C` is the sum of the match value `W` and the risk value `R`

I would like to calculate `C` with a function.

[image]

[image]

1. `W` = your match value
2. `W0`= your previous match value
3. `Wi`= the match value of the player you defeated
4. `Wj`= the match value of the player you lost to
5. `s`= sum of the matches you won
6. `N`= sum of the matches you lost

Now I would like to write a function that calculates `C` with a tibble input of the matches played and the match value of the opponents.
(I've already learned [how to estimate a desired `W`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681854/calculate-ranking-match-value-in-swiss-tennis))

`results <- tibble(match=c(1,2,3),match_value_opponent=c(2.4,4.5,3.4), result=c("win","loss","win"))`

The previous match value is a constant:
`w0 <- 2`

I think the function would look like this, but I am not sure how to implement the two formulas in `R`

`calculate_w= function(results)(...)`

### Update1:

With the function from the kind answer from theN below I do not get the expected results, especially not expected `W`.

Reprex with the data from [this accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681854/calculate-ranking-match-value-in-swiss-tennis):

```r
library(tidyverse)

calculate_c= function(tibble,w0){
  
  tibble_out <- tibble %>%
    mutate(e_pos_wi = case_when(result == "win"  ~ exp(match_value_opponent)),
           e_neg_wj = case_when(result == "loss" ~ exp(-match_value_opponent))) %>%
    summarise(sum_e_pos_wi = sum(e_pos_wi, na.rm = T),
              sum_e_neg_wj = sum(e_neg_wj, na.rm = T)) %>%
    mutate(e_pos_w0 = exp(w0),
           e_neg_w0 = exp(w0),
           W = (1/2) * (log(sum_e_pos_wi + e_pos_w0) - log(sum_e_neg_wj + e_neg_w0)),
           R = (1/6) * (log(sum_e_pos_wi + e_pos_w0) - log(sum_e_neg_wj + e_neg_w0)),
           C = W + R)
  
  return(tibble_out[,c("W","R","C")])
  
}


# make a tibble with 15 wins vs a player with a W of 3400 (same input as described in the question/answer on Mathematica linked above) 
results <- tibble(match=paste(1:15),match_value_opponent=c(rep(3.400,15)), result=c(rep("win",15)))

# calculate W with the same W0 as in the Mathematica question/answer
calculate_c(tibble = results, w0=2.354)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       W     R     C
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1.89 0.630  2.52

#expected output
# W at least 3.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Update2:

These are the formulas directly copied from the link above:

[image]
[image]

### Update3:

Because of the comments (the given formulas might not be unequivocal), I contacted Swiss Tennis for clarification. They sent me updated formulas (sorry for the quality, these are the originals):
[image]
[image]
Where `WA` = `W0`
Unfortunately, they did not provide an example of the formula in use.

Comment: Is the first $\ln$ term supposed to be $\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{s} (e^{w_i} + e^{w_0})\right)$ or is it $\ln\left((\sum_{i=1}^{s} e^{w_i}) + e^{w_0}\right)$? That is, is $e^{w_0}$ supposed to be in the sum or not? In the answer you link to they use the former but the answer below assumes the second. The same question applies for the other three $\ln$ terms

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure about that. Are the two formulas above mathematically not unequivocal?  My knowledge in mathematics is unfortunately very limited.

Comment: Sorry to say that I've seen the notation used both ways before. Brackets can be used after the summation symbol, or anything that's not in the sum can be put before the summation like in this formula: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/8b9e6c129af731072d3ef931f3e52ae6ff7bb8b7 I would guess that the answer below has the correct interpretation but it's just a guess.

Comment: Do you have an example of the formula in use? Or is it based on a formula used by another organization?

Comment: Ok actually I'm pretty sure that the answer below is correct and the one on math SE previous one is wrong. If a player has played no matches then the answer below would say that their W score is still w_0 whereas the other interpretation would make their W score undefined

Comment: Unfortunately there is no publised example of the formula in use nor does another organization use this formula. However, I wrote the Swiss Tennis Association and asked for clarification regarding the formula.

Comment: I've given new answers to both this question and your MathSE one - hope that helps!

Comment: Just spotted a mistake in your question - in your nicely formatted maths equations, the formula for R should have a '+' not a '-' between the two ln terms. I'm amending my answer to correct this. I was wondering why R was just equal to W/3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
W = function(res, w0) {
    # scores when you win
    wi = res$match_value_opponent[res$result == "win"]
    # first half of W
    w1 = log(sum(exp(wi)) + exp(w0))
    
    # scores when you lose
    wj = res$match_value_opponent[res$result == "loss"]
    # second half of W
    w2 = log(sum(exp(-wj)) + exp(-w0))

    return(0.5*(w1 - w2))
}

R = function(res, w0) {
    # scores when you win
    wi = res$match_value_opponent[res$result == "win"]
    # first half of W
    w1 = log(sum(exp(wi)) + exp(w0))
    
    # scores when you lose
    wj = res$match_value_opponent[res$result == "loss"]
    # second half of W
    w2 = log(sum(exp(-wj)) + exp(-w0))
    
    return((1/6)*(w1 + w2))
}

C = function(res, w0) {
    w = W(res, w0)
    print("W")
    print(w)
    r = R(res, w0)
    print("R")
    print(r)
    return(w + r)
}
```

I haven't written it in the most efficient way, but you have separate functions for calculating W and R if you need them.

If I run

```
results2 <- tibble(match=paste(1:15),match_value_opponent=c(rep(3.400,15)), result=c(rep("win",15)))
C(results2, 2)
```

I get

```
[1] "W"
[1] 4.062178
[1] "R"
[1] 0.6873927
[1] 4.749571
```

I think this makes more sense - your W score should be greater than 2 after winning 15 matches against players with match values of 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, feel free to modify the function to return intermediate parts of the calculation if needed.

```
calculate_c= function(tibble){
  
  tibble_out <- tibble %>%
    mutate(e_pos_wi = case_when(result == "win"  ~ exp(match_value_opponent)),
           e_neg_wj = case_when(result == "loss" ~ exp(-match_value_opponent))) %>%
    summarise(sum_e_pos_wi = sum(e_pos_wi, na.rm = T),
              sum_e_neg_wj = sum(e_neg_wj, na.rm = T)) %>%
    mutate(e_pos_w0 = exp(2),
           e_neg_w0 = exp(-2),
           W = (1/2) * (log(sum_e_pos_wi + e_pos_w0) - log(sum_e_neg_wj + e_neg_w0)),
           R = (1/6) * (log(sum_e_pos_wi + e_pos_w0) - log(sum_e_neg_wj + e_neg_w0)),
           C = W + R)

  return(tibble_out[, "C"])
  
}

calculate_c(tibble = results)
```